# React using method parameter as an object key to update state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactive-programming

How can I use a function parameter as a property name to update state i.e.

```
onStudentPinChange = (propertyName, e) => {
    this.setState({
      formFields: { ...this.state.formFields, propertyName: e.target.value }
    });
};
```

the code above throw error

I would like to use that `propertyName` variable as an object key I googled and tried many different techniques like `this.state.formFields[propertName]`

I am creating a new web-app I have a few form fields which needed to be filled to login to the admin area. I have three methods which are basically doing the same thing just updating the relevant state

```
onStudentPinChange = (propertyName, e) => {
    var item = { ...this.state.formFields };
    item[propertyName] = e.target.value;
    console.log(item);
    this.setState({
      formFields: { ...this.state.formFields, studentPin: e.target.value }
    });
  };

  onCNICChange = (propertyName, e) => {
    this.setState({
      formFields: { ...this.state.formFields, cnic: e.target.value }
    });
  };

  onPasswordChange = (propertyName, e) => {
    this.setState({
      formFields: { ...this.state.formFields, password: e.target.value }
    });
  };



<InputField
        type="text"
        name="student_pin"
        value={this.state.formFields.studentPin}
        placeholder="Student Pin"
        onChange={this.onStudentPinChange.bind(this, "studentPin")}
        faClassName="fa-user"
      />
```

I would like only to have one function that updates all three fields just using that properName

Regards

Comment: You could create a code snippet in the editor, and paste your javascript code there. Aside from that, ensure that your code is properly indented, and you could also surround it with three backticks like `\`\`\``

Comment: Make sure you do what the message says. Also make sure the code block is preceded by a blank line. Also scroll through the whole input to make sure there are no "left overs" you overlooked.

Comment: thanks trincot and Keno Clayton I eventually have it posted with your help and suggestions

Comment: You can use `{[propertyName]: value}` [more details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015)

Comment: thank you @more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow. You can achieve this by wrapping property name around brackets so that it evaluates the key as a variable and not actually propertyName.

```
onStudentPinChange = (propertyName, e) => {
    this.setState({
        formFields: {
            ...this.state.formFields,
            [propertyName]: e.target.value
        }
    });
};
```